# Limit of a sequence of test functions

Tags: distribution-theory

$ B(x,\frac{1}{n}) $ be  open balls in $ \mathbb{R}^{N} $ with $ N\geq2 $,  and $ (\phi_{n})$ be a sequence of test functions with support in $  B(x,\frac{1}{n}) $ such that $ \phi_{n}=1 $ on $ B(x,\frac{1}{2n}) $, for all $ n $. Suppose there exists a sequence  $(z_{n})\in  B(x,\frac{1}{n}) $ such that 
$$ \phi_{n}(z_{n})\not=0, $$   for all $ n $. Can we conclude that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \phi_{n}(z_{n})=1?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heuristically speaking, for each $n$, let us consider the sets
\begin{align}
W_n:= B\left(x,\frac{1}{2n}\right) \subset V_n:=B\left(x,\frac{3}{4n}\right) \subset U_n:=B\left(x,\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}
and construct a radial nonnegative test function $\phi_n$ such that $\phi_n \equiv 1$ on $B(x, \frac{1}{2n})$ and $\phi_n \equiv 0$ on $B(x, 1/n)^c$ while $\phi_n(y)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $y \in B(x, \frac{3}{4n})^c$.

If we choose $z_n \in B(x, 1/n)\backslash B(x, \frac{3}{4n})$ such that $\phi_n(z_n) \neq 0$, then $\phi_n(z_n)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ which means
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \phi_n(z_n) \leq \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
Hence we are done if we could show such a family of test functions exists.

**Technical Details**

Suppose $\varphi(|x|)$ is your standard radial bump function constructed from
\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2} & \ \ \text{ if } x>0\\
0& \ \ \text{ if } x\leq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
with the property $\varphi(|x|)\geq 0, \operatorname{supp}\varphi \subset B(0, 1)$ and $\int \varphi=1$.

For each $n$, we consider $W_n \subset V_n \subset U_n$ as above. Moreover, notice we have
\begin{align}
d(\bar W_n, V_n^c)= \frac{1}{4n}  \ \ \text{ and } \ \ d(\bar V_n, U_n^c) = \frac{1}{4n}.
\end{align}
For convenience, we shall set $r_n=\frac{1}{4n}$. 
Next, consider the function
\begin{align}
\varphi_{r_n}(y) = \frac{1}{r_n^d}\varphi\left(\frac{y}{r_n}\right)
\end{align}
which has the properties $\operatorname{supp}\varphi_{r_n} \subset B(0, r_n)$ and
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\varphi_{r_n}(x)\ dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\varphi\left(\frac{x}{r_n} \right)\frac{dx}{r_n^d} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi(u)\ du = 1.
\end{align}
Lastly, consider the function
\begin{align}
\phi_n(x) = \varphi_{r_n}\ast \chi_{V_n}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\varphi_{r_n}(x-y)\chi_{V_n}(y)\ dy.
\end{align}

Let us check $\phi_n$ has the desired properties.

Observe if $x \in W_n$, then $\operatorname{supp}\varphi_{r_n} (x-\cdot)\subset B(x, r_n) \subset V_n$ since $d(\bar W_n, V_n^c) = \frac{1}{4n}$. Thus, it follows
\begin{align}
\phi_n(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\varphi_{r_n}(x-y)\chi_{V_n}(y)\ dy = \int_{B(x, r_n)}\varphi_{r_n}(x-y)\ dy  = 1.
\end{align}
Likewise, if $x \in U_n^c$ we see that $\operatorname{supp}\varphi_{r_n}(x-\cdot) \subset V_n^c$ which means
\begin{align}
\phi_n(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\varphi_{r_n}(x-y)\chi_{V_n}(y)\ dy = \int_{B(x, r_n)}\varphi_{r_n}(x-y)\cdot 0\ dy  = 0.
\end{align}
Hence $\phi_n$ is supported in $U_n$. It's also clear that $\phi_n$ is $C^\infty$ since it's obtain from a convolution of a function against a $C^\infty$ function.

The last property to check is $\phi_n(y) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $y \in U_n\backslash V_n$.

Let $x \in U_n\backslash V_n$, then we see $B(x, r_n) \cap V_n$ miss at least half of $B(x, r_n)$ which means
\begin{align}
\phi_n(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi_{r_n}(x-y)\chi_{V_n}(y)\ dy = \int_{B(x, r_n)\cap V}\varphi_{r_n}(x-y)\chi_{V_n}(y)\ dy \leq \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{align}